# Use dismiss() to pop view from NavigationStack with different animation

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-animation

I am using the @Environment(.dismiss) private var dismiss and than dismiss() to pop current view from NavigationStack. In my app it should look like going forward however, rather than backwards.

When I use dismiss() the animation is sliding from left to right indicating going back. How can I change that to go from right to left, or any other animation for that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a NavigationLink you could utilize a `switch-statement`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var currentView: ShowView = .PARENT
    
    var body: some View {
        switch currentView {
        case .PARENT:
            NavigationStack {
                Button("Show Subview") {
                    withAnimation {
                        currentView = .SUBVIEW
                    }
                }
            }
            .transition(.backslide)
        case .SUBVIEW:
            NavigationStack {
                Button("Show Parent") {
                    withAnimation {
                        currentView = .PARENT
                    }
                }
            }
            .transition(.backslide)
        }
    }
}
```

For this example I used my own enum:

```
enum ShowView {
    case PARENT, SUBVIEW
}
```

And for the backslide (which I guess is the transition you wanted):

```
extension AnyTransition {
    static var backslide: AnyTransition {
        AnyTransition.asymmetric(
            insertion: .move(edge: .trailing),
            removal: .move(edge: .leading))}
}
```

The result looks like this (I added black background):
[image: To make it clear I added some black background]

Feel free to add more information if that is not what you wanted.

Comment: This looks great, I haven't thought about using switch statement to move between 2 views, I only focused on using NavigationLink from one to another. Thank you very much.